# Indesign: can't get rid of padding on Auto Resized text boxed

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, resize

I auto resized a text box to "height only", but is still has a little white space between the bottom of the text and the bottom of the box. The inset spacing is all set to zero. Any ideas as to what this could be?

Answer (score 0):

Okay looks like I had copied the same box a bunch of time that had an extra line break with no text on it.

Ooops.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Don't forget to choose your own answer as best if this solved it for you.